# Почему node.js не показывает весь callstack при возникновении exeption?

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, исключения, exception-handler

Доброго времени суток друзья, я пришёл из мира **.net** и мне не понятно почему если exeption случился во внешней библиотеке **node.js** и если я не обернул вызов этой внешней библиотеки в try/catch то я никогда не узнаю какой именно участок моего кода вызвал exeption, так как в выводе exeption'а будет только то место где он произошёл внутри библиотеки?

На скрине просто один из примеров такого случая. Как можно увидеть тут нет ни строчки из моего клиентского кода и callstack обрывается внутри библиотечной функции:

[image: nodejs exception обрывается во внешней библиотеке]

Неужели в мире **node.js** мы всё должны оборачивать в try/catch только для того что бы не потерять callstack нашего вызова внешнего кода???

Один из участников сообщества предложил такое решение проблемы:

> попробуй в свой главный файл добавить отлов. возможно здесь будет
>   более удобный стектрейс. ну а так, да, хорошо бы использовать try
>   catch в тех местах где может вывалиться исклчение.
>
> ```
> process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {  
>    console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);  
>    // Application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here 
> });
> ```

Comment: а что не так с приведенным стектрейсом?

Comment: @Grundy проблема в том что в нем не видно какой именно вызов клиентского кода привел к исключению

Comment: Такие ошибки могут происходить вообще без вашего кода. Работает себе библиотека на фоне, какие-то запросы делает, и тут реджект промиса не обработан. Будет такая ошибка. И побороть это даже try-catch не сможет, потому что код библиотеки может быть не сплошной, а асинхронные колбэки, которые выполняются позже, чем ваш try-catch. Это усугубляется тем, что в документации методов часто "забывают" сообщить о возможных исключениях. И если не написать глобальный отлов, то будет падать процесс.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev А как написать глобальный отлов, может существует какая-то идиома?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Выше вы уже вроде написали пример, кем-то посоветованный, я это и имел в виду. Он не всегда помогает в отлове конкретного места, но позволяет не убивать процесс, как и "uncaughtException".

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Да согласен с тем что некая фоновая библиотека получив например какой-то некорректный запрос из вне может упасть и без нашего клиентского кода, и возможно это именно тот случай, но дело в том что я встречал случаи когда источником эксепшена в библиотеке был именно клиентский код и там так же не возможно было найти концов, всё что мы видели это то что экспшн был в библиотеке а кто его вызвал неизвестно...

Answer (score 1):

По дефолту, `stack trace` ограничен 10-ю значениями
https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_stacktracelimit

Comment: Спасибо, позновательная информация. Но как можно видеть на скрине там вложенность как будто бы больше 10?

Comment: `The default value is 10 but may be set to any valid JavaScript number.`